# I get a 404 error when trying to access a .jsp file under my WEB-INF directory and I can't figure out why

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I've looked at every post I could find on the this issue but every time I do it seems like my configurations are as they should be.

When I type in the URL http:/localhost:8080/ I get the correct index.jsp displayed, but when I type in http:/localhost:8080/account I get the 404 error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Project Structure**

```
ProjectName  
-v .idea  
-v src    
---v main  
-----v java  
-------v springmvc.controllers  
---------> AccountController.java  
-----v resources  
-------> application-context.xml  
-------> log4j.properties  
-----v webapp  
-------v WEB-INF  
---------v views  
-----------> account.jsp  
---------> web.xml  
-------> index.jsp  
-> pom.xml
```

**AccountController.java**

```
package springmvc.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView findAllAccounts() throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("account");
        mav.addObject("someText", "Listing all accounts!");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{accountId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView findAccount(@PathVariable int accountId, Model     model) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("account");
        mav.addObject("someText", String.format("Showing account %d", accountId));
        return mav;
    }
}
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**account.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<h1>${someText}</h1>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<% Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, the time is <%= cal.getTime() %> </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.projectName</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.5.49</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {`

 above your controller class, Therefore your controller will only map requests with /accounts header only, 

 As you have added 
 `@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)` in your method also, the controller will be looking for a accounts/accounts/ requests to execute the particular method.

Try http:/localhost:8080/account/account 
or remove the class level request mapping.